# How to capture a screen shot of all spaces

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Regularly I use more than 4 spaces in my Macbook Pro ( lion/10.7.1 ).

Can I get a screenshot of all spaces at one time ?

Comment: Not aware of any apps that can do this, but I'd imagine you could write an AppleScript or record an Automator workflow that would do it. (That still wouldn't be instantaneous, though.)

Comment: Thanks @scottishwildcat. Your suggestion is a good reason for me to get into AppleScript.

Comment: That would create some really massive .PNG files that would likely require a great deal of editing, scaling, compression, and conversion to another file format afterwards. Image manipulation might need to be a part of your AppleScripting also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screencapture ~/Desktop/1.png
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code 124 using control down' # ctrl-right
sleep 0.5
screencapture ~/Desktop/2.png
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code 123 using control down' # ctrl-left
# montage ~/Desktop/1.png ~/Desktop/2.png -tile 2x1 -geometry +2+2 ~/Desktop/`date '+%y%m%d%H%M%S'`.png
```

[montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) comes with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you can get all Desktops to completely show on one screen, then yes.  That will be a trick that will make you famous.  8-)

I suspect the only such screenshot you can get of all spaces at once is to capture when using Mission Control.

You could cobble together a screenshot by combining the individual shots in Preview, or stitch them together with a photo app, and then taking a picture of the result.

Comment: Thanks @modelamac. For current work I involved, I was take one hundred more screenshot of more than 4 spaces every day. I am tired of that. Thus why I want to find a smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can click F3, view all the desktops in the mission control, and then use Command-Shift-4 to capture that screenshot.

Comment: thanks ron, but your method is what I look for